# Sniffing usb serial connection

Tags: serial-port, user-interface, wireshark

I'm trying to read the usb/serial connection under Ubuntu 15.04 without beeing a real 'member' of the connection. Since there can only be 2 instances reading/writing on the bus.
I've used modprobe usbmon to start the usbmonitor and now I'm trying to read the connection using wireshark. It shows usbmon alright, but it seems to me, as if there are only headers and protocol-packages sent.
If I use a terminal emulator to send some numbers I can't find my own messages.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).
Depending on permissions, you might have to run it as root.

Below is an example of socat recording the transmission between `picocom` and a pyboard using a serial connection over USB on FreeBSD.

Socat is started (as root) like this:

```
socat -d -v -x PTY,link=/tmp/serial,wait-slave,rawer \
/dev/cuaU0,rawer > & socat.txt
```

And picocom is started (also as root) like this:

```
# picocom /tmp/serial
```

Part of the contents of `socat.txt`. Data from the board is preceded by “<”, what I type is preceded by “>”

```
< 2017/10/01 15:37:57.488955  length=48 from=0 to=47
2e 32 20 6f 6e 20 32 30 31 37 2d 30 38 2d 32 33  .2 on 2017-08-23
3b 20 50 59 42 76 31 2e 31 20 77 69 74 68 20 53  ; PYBv1.1 with S
54 4d 33 32 46 34 30 35 52 47 0d 0a              TM32F405RG..
54 79 70 65                                      Type
--
> 2017/10/01 15:38:01.181435  length=1 from=0 to=0
0d                                               .
--
< 2017/10/01 15:38:01.247992  length=37 from=48 to=84
20 22 68 65 6c 70 28 29 22 20 66 6f 72 20 6d 6f   "help()" for mo
72 65 20 69 6e 66 6f 72 6d 61 74 69 6f 6e 2e 0d  re information..
0a                                               .
3e 3e 3e 20                                      >>> 
--
> 2017/10/01 15:38:05.413958  length=1 from=1 to=1
68                                               h
--
< 2017/10/01 15:38:05.416064  length=6 from=85 to=90
0d 0a                                            ..
3e 3e 3e 20                                      >>> 
--
> 2017/10/01 15:38:06.290046  length=1 from=2 to=2
65                                               e
--
< 2017/10/01 15:38:06.292079  length=1 from=91 to=91
68                                               h
--
> 2017/10/01 15:38:06.579576  length=1 from=3 to=3
6c                                               l
--
< 2017/10/01 15:38:06.581082  length=1 from=92 to=92
65                                               e
--
> 2017/10/01 15:38:06.816570  length=1 from=4 to=4
70                                               p
--
```